# Can i use a javascript variable in an if sentence in scala in play framework?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a dropdown list:

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

And I get the selected value as such:

```
var e = document.getElementById("sel");
var val= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

But what I need is to use the "val" variable in a play framework Scala if sentence like:

```
@if(svor.rettsvar == val){
    <p><b>@svor.svor_texti</b></p>
}
```

and to make it update if I change the selected value.

Best regards, Björn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix Scala and JavaScript scopes.... Actually I have no even idea, how to explain it :/

Scala syntax is compiled at the runtime to some HTML code, and JavaScript is performed on the client side, so it's not possible to interact the Scala with JS... If you'll look into HTML code generated from Scala view, you'll understand.

Most probably you can resolve your problems with using ONLY JS conditions.